# Label two attributes with more than 2 rows

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have the following dataset

| ID | Date | Thickness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-2022 | 0,02 |
| A | 04-2022 | 0,04 |
| B | 01-2022 | 0,01 |
| B | 04-2022 | 0,02 |
| B | 06-2022 | 0,02 |
| B | 08-2022 | 0,05 |
| C | 01-2022 | 0,00 |

I want to label Date+Thickness. I'm good with customize label and do:

```
"Date"||'\n'||"Thickness"
```

I'm ok, but if a point like point B has more than two observations in Date and Thickness it won't show. It only shows up to two observations.

This is what I want:

[image]

What's the course of action?

Comment: Yes I can, I made a quick draw to show what I want QGIS to do. Had to hide the ID of the points. https://imgur.com/aSM15ox

Answer (score 4):

```sql
-- make an array of the dates per ID
with_variable('dates',
    array_agg(
        "Date",
        group_by:="ID"
    ),
    
    -- make an array of the thicknesses per ID
    with_variable('thicknesses',
        array_agg(
            "Thickness",
            group_by:="ID"
        ),
    
        -- the case statement is to ensure the label is created only once per "ID" group
        case
            when
                $id = array_min(
                          array_agg(
                              $id,
                              group_by:="ID"
                          )
                      )
                
            then
                -- convert the array to a string, using '\n' as the delimiter for the string so each element appears on a new line
                array_to_string(  

                    -- loop through the arrays and concatenate the thickness to the date (with some space in between)
                    array_foreach(
                        generate_series(1, array_length(@dates)),
                            array_get(@dates, @element-1) || '   ' || array_get(@thicknesses, @element-1)
                    ), '\n'  -- '\n' as the delimiter for the array_to_string function
                )
        end
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Matt. What an absolute legend. If you don't mind asking, what do I need to read or pratice in order to learn as much as this level you demonstrated ?

Comment: You're welcome. I am a big fan of the expression engine in QGIS. A good place to start would be the [tutorial on the QGIS page itself](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#the-expression-string-builder), I find it helpful to look through all the [functions and their various parameters](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html) also, checking out questions and answers using expressions on this site, and a lot of trial and error :D . I am sure there other resources too, various blogs and YouTube tutorials etc.

Comment: The great thing about the expression editor in QGIS is the live preview you get of the output at the bottom of the window. You can see directly what will be returned and decide how to deal with it. It really helps when building up from a basic expression to something more complicated.